# How to publish to Nexus the artifact generated by a Gradle project in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, gradle, nexus

I have a Gradle project with the following `uploadArchives` configuration to publish its artifact to Nexus:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: 'http://releasesrepo')
            snapshotRepository(url: 'http://snapshotsrepo')
        }
    }
}
```

As you see there are no credentials in this configuration.

This build will be run from Jenkins as a Freestyle project so I will just have to specify in Build - Invoke Gradle Script - Tasks -> `build upload`

What's the right way to configure the Nexus credentials from Jenkins and pass them to the Gradle taks (I don't want them in the Git repo with the source code)?

Comment: Jenkins Credentials Store and define them in the global config file provider (init.gradle) Script if I correctly remember...

Answer (score 1):

There are three different ways:

1.Using environmental variables

```
def nexusUser = hasProperty('nexusUsername') ? nexusUsername : System.getenv('nexusUsername')
def nexusPassword = hasProperty('nexusPassword') ? nexusPassword : System.getenv('nexusPassword')
def nexusReleaseUrl = hasProperty('nexusReleaseUrl') ? nexusReleaseUrl : System.getenv('nexusReleaseUrl')
def nexusSnapshotUrl = hasProperty('nexusSnapshotUrl') ? nexusSnapshotUrl : System.getenv('nexusSnapshotUrl')

repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
        repository(url: nexusReleaseUrl) {
            authentication(userName: nexusUser, password: nexusPassword);
        }
        snapshotRepository(url: nexusSnapshotUrl) {
            authentication(userName: nexusUser, password: nexusPassword);
        }
    }
```

}

2.Using ~/.gradle/gradle.properties (remember is under the user jenkins)

```
nexusUser=user
nexusPass=password

uploadArchives {
  def nexusUser = "${nexusUsername}"
  def nexusPassword = "${nexusPassword}"

  repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
        repository(url: 'your nexus releases') {
            authentication(userName: nexusUser, password: nexusPassword);
        }
        snapshotRepository(url: 'your nexus snapshot') {
            authentication(userName: nexusUser, password: nexusPassword);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

3.Using the global credentials

You have an example [here](https://github.com/carloscaverobarca/gradle-release-example/blob/master/build.gradle) (it is for Travis) if you want to have a look